# Open link in safari from inapp browser

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari, instagram-api

I have the link for my website on instagram bio but I want to redirect to safari browser when my website is loaded on inapp browser.

I tried with **target="_blank"**, the "**website.com/?inbrowser=no**" options and window.open javascript too, nothing worked and my website still is loaded on the inappbrowser of Instagram.

Is there any javascript/html code to avoid this and open the link in safari?

This doesn't worked neither:

```
<script>
    var str = navigator.userAgent;
    var i = str.indexOf("Instagram");
    if (i != -1) {
      document.write("<button><a target='_blank' href='http://website.com/?inbrowser=no'>Proceed to Safari5</a></button>");
       //window.location=encodeURI('http://website.com/?inbrowser=no');
    }

</script>
```